# Slick 3.0.0 and Scala 2.10.4

Tags: slick-3.0

I was trying to create a scala program with slick 3.0 and I am getting the following error:

**Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in BasicDriver.class refers to term typesafe
in package com which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling BasicDriver.class.**

I am using scala 2.10.4 and slick 2.10-3.0.0-RC1 and my IDE is IDEA 14.0.3 community edition

Any clue about this compilation error will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how a BasicDriver.class defintion looks like

```
package scala.slick.profile
trait BasicDriver extends scala.AnyRef with scala.slick.profile.BasicProfile {
   val profile : scala.slick.profile.BasicProfile = { /* compiled code */ }
  override def toString() : java.lang.String = { /* compiled code */ }
  final val driverConfig : com.typesafe.config.Config = { /* compiled code */     }
  protected[this] def loadDriverConfig : com.typesafe.config.Config = { /*   compiled code */ }
```

}

The error :

```
Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in BasicDriver.class refers to term typesafe in package com which is not available. It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling BasicDriver.class
```

is saying that com.typesafe for (com.typesafe.config.Config) is missing from the classpath .

I think the problem is with the dependencies added , try the master snapshot :

```
  "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.10" % "3.0.0-M1"
```